# NSArray removeLastObject is not declared?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I've got pretty simple code out here:

```
NSArray* divisions = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", system("ssh git@nebula \"ls\"")] 
    componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
[divisions removeLastObject];
```

And I get:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeLastObject'
```

Sorry if this is quite a nooby question, but this is who I am at Objective-C. My guess is that I'm messing with pointers, I'm still not certain how they work and how to work with them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add or remove objects like that from an immutable NSArray instance. You have to use an NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableDivisions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:divisions];
[mutableDivisions removeLastObject];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says that NSArray is a subclass of NSMutableArray, shouldn't it inherit it's methods?